# mysql and c# - compare date with today (just the day)

Tags: c#, mysql, date, compare

I have a colomn name LastOnline which is define as DataType=Datetime
I enter him the values as

```
update office.router set LastOnline=NOW() where IP=deviceip;
```

working as should

but how do I compare it to check only devices that aren't online today without the time , just the date part of the timestamp?

so when he will get ping from him today, he will try to ping it the next day?

I have try

```
    SELECT
*
FROM  office.router
where
LastOnline != Date(curdate())
```

but it didn't work - gave me the full list
what is wrong?

Comment: if lastonline is a time stamp as well you need to add the Date(LastOnline) != ... to your query

Comment: working - thanks , I thought I don't need tou use Date() if the datatype is date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't to do date of curdate() because curdate is already a date:

```
SELECT * FROM sample.table1
where Date(LastOnline) = curdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks , 
this is the correct way to write this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM sample.table1
where
Date(LastOnline) = Date(curdate())
```

working